# How do I keep checkbox states while scrolling in recyclerView?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255192/checkbox-visibility-changes-while-scrolling-recyclerview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427889/checkbox-in-recyclerview-keeps-on-checking-different-items) but I haven't been able to adapt these solutions to fix my problem. Can you help?

I check checkboxes, scroll down in my `recyclerview`, when I scroll back up, checkboxes are unchecked, or else different ones are checked.

I get why it's happening - as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427889/checkbox-in-recyclerview-keeps-on-checking-different-items): you should add a `boolean variable` into your `onBindViewHolder` to keep your item's selection status, which I believe I am doing with:

```
theContactsList.get(pos).setSelected(isChecked);
```

but still checkbox state is not preserved.

Here's my code:

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        //bind the views into the ViewHolder
        //selectPhoneContact is an instance of the SelectPhoneContact class.
        //We will assign each row of the recyclerview to contain details of selectPhoneContact:

        //The number of rows will match the number of phone contacts
        final SelectPhoneContact selectPhoneContact = theContactsList.get(position);

        //if the row is a matching contact
        if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == 1)

        {
            //in the title textbox in the row, put the corresponding name etc...
            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).title.setText(selectPhoneContact.getName());
            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).phone.setText(selectPhoneContact.getPhone());
            //((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setText("Cheeckbox" + position);
            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setChecked(theContactsList.get(position).isSelected);
            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setTag(position);

          //  ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setChecked(selectPhoneContact.isSelected());



            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           // ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnClickListener(new CompoundButton.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
                    //pos is the row number that the clicked checkbox exists in
                    Integer pos = (Integer) ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.getTag();

                    //set the value of the checkbox accordingly onCheckedChange,
                    //to true or false
                    theContactsList.get(pos).setSelected(isChecked);

                    if(isChecked == true ) {
                       // ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setChecked(true);
                        Toast.makeText(context_type, theContactsList.get(pos).getPhone() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    else {
                       // ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setChecked(false);
                        Toast.makeText(context_type, theContactsList.get(pos).getPhone() + " unclicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            });

            }

    }
```

Comment: IMO, it would be best if save the checked state to your model class or in a list.

Comment: @Max Would you suggest any posts/tutorials?

Comment: Your implementation seems correct. You are keeping checkbox state saved in a list. Can you try one thing? Put this line at the top of `onBindView` after you check for the itemViewType, `(MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)`

Comment: @Napster Tried that, it didn't fix it. I am implementing Ugurcan's suggestion below, will keep you posted. I will be keeping the line of code you say above, as I do believe it is more helpful than harmful - from what I have read.

Comment: @max is right! You should save the check state in your model. Also you can use this library, see ViewStates https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter

Answer (score 1):

Have a `HashMap<String, Boolean>` instance inside your recycler adapter. Keys should be something that uniquely defines your each item, and values indicate whether item is checked or not. Whenever you click a checkbox, call `map.put(item.getId(), !map.get(item.getId())` (don't forget to check initial not-exist case). And finally inside `onBindViewHolder()` method, always set your item's checkbox according to the state hold in `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Culprit is your `OnCheckedChangeListener` - keep in mind it fires off even when you change check state programatically.

This is what's currently happening with your implementation:

1. You bind ViewHolder 1 to position 0
2. You scroll down, ViewHolder 1 is removed
3. ViewHolder 1 is reused and bound to position 5 (example)

Then this is executed:

```
((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setChecked(theContactsList.get(5).isSelected);
((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setTag(5);
```

But checkBox already has an `OnCheckedChangeListener` so it's executed as soon as `setChecked()` is called and this happens:

```
// 0 is the tag you assigned to a view, but we're binding item 5 now
theContactsList.get(0).setSelected(isChecked);
```

You effectively set your check state of position 0 to state of position 5 (which will most likely by false).

You're also creating a ton of `OnCheckedChangeListener` objects when scrolling through the list, you can create only one in ViewHolders constructor and it will work just as fine since it fetches current position when called.

For solution, simply move your `setTag()` higher (before `setChecked()`), but honestly you should use `getAdapterPosition()` in your `OnCheckedChangeListener` instead of a tag work around.

Answer (score 0):

simply write this one line before calling your adapter.

```
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(100000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! Your answer could be even better if you explained what the problem was and how the code you propose here resolves the problem. Also, don't forget to use the appropriate formatting for pieces of code and quotes. This makes questions and answers easier to read and more likely to get upvotes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);` at the top of your code :

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);

    //other stuff
}
```